# How to make a complex file download functionality with Blazor server?

Tags: c#, download, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application. I want to allow the user to download files but the content of the files needs to be built dynamically.

Basically the application shows reports to the user based on filters and etc. and I want the user to have the option to download whatever he is currently seeing.

I know I can make a "link button" that points to a Razor page that returns some sort of `FileContentResult` in its `OnGet` method but I have no idea how to pass any data to that so that the correct report file can be built.

I know there is an alternative that uses JavaScript but, as far as I know, it's more cumbersome and I'm not sure if it is any better.

I thought about doing a request to some sort of REST/WebAPI (which would allow me to pass arguments and stuff) but I cannot seem to get a WebAPI and Blazor Server projects run at the same time. The only partial success I've had is adding a WebAPI project to my Blazor Server solution and starting both. But then, while debugging, for some reason, both processes stop when I download the file.

Also the application must be hosted on Azure Web app and am not sure how feasible it would be to run both projects at the same time.

So, how can I make my Blazor Server allow the user to download a file but generate the file dynamically based on what the user is seeing on his browser?

Comment: Well, the first question I'd have is-- what format will the file itself be?  An image?  A pdf?  An SVG markup file?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, CSV file.

Comment: Okay, what input does your logic need to generate that file?  An ID?  Does it actually need any Blazor, or is it all C# logic?

Comment: Server needs a list of the items displayed on the browser screen (which, ironically, it retrieves itself (the server retrieves them and shows them to the user)). Basically a list of `Item` objects.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, btw I've since decided it would be best to use a controller for that, just have to figure out how to pass it the list.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript alternative is very straightforward.

```
export function saveAsFile(filename, bytesBase64) {
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        //Download document in Edge browser
        var data = window.atob(bytesBase64);
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([bytes.buffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + bytesBase64;
        document.body.appendChild(link); // Needed for Firefox
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
```

create a bytestream of whatever content you want to create and call this function through IJSInterop. I have used it in blazor server and it works well.

**Please note** :  I found this piece of code online but I don't remember from where. I will be happy to give credit to the original author if someone knows the source.

Comment: While a valid answer, I suppose (haven't tested it) - *disdain for JavaScript*. Would this allow the browser to pass data to the server about what is displayed on screen?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There is no 'client' as such in blazor server. This would be the flow: user makes changes to the filter, you capture that state, when the user clicks on "download" you build the report and pass on that report to the function above.

Comment: The state of the application is maintained entirely on the server side. This JavaScript function is only for enabling whatever byte stream that the page gives.

Comment: By client I meant the user and his browser session.